# How do you scale a design resolution to other resolutions with Pygame?

Tags: python, pygame, game-engine

So in every Pygame example I've seen, there seems to be a resolution the game is designed to be played on and that's it. No options for setting higher or lower resolutions. If you do change the resolution via display.set_mode, then the scale of the game textures/graphics get out of whack and the game becomes unplayable.

In all the examples I've seen, it looks like you would have to actually create different sized texture sets for each target resolution... Which seems ridiculous. That leads me to my question.

If I design a game based on a standard resolution of 480x270, is it possible to simply scale the output of that surface to 1080p (or 1440p, 4k, etc) while still utilizing the game assets built for 480x270? If so, can anyone post an example of how this can be accomplished? Any tips or pointers would also be appreciated.

Comment: Well i would imagine it's mostly a matter of sticking with an aspect ratio and defining a function that converts all your assets to the proper size with pygame.transform.scale().  Should be pretty easy honestly.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that much. I was just hoping there would be an actual example of this somewhere. I've tried out about 20 or so games from pygame.org and none of them use transform in this way. There must be an easier way of doing this without restructuring how your textures get loaded. In a game with lots of textures, this would get tedious fast and I'm sure it's not great for game performance... But I'll try it if there are no other options.

Comment: If you restricted the user's resolution choice to  acceptable aspect ratio choices to your texture pack, you could simply scale your sprite's image based on your resolution upon instantiation. You'd have to lock the option to change resolution before going that route though. Been toying with the idea, might have a demo for you shortly.

Comment: Actually, beyond "scaling code" - there is a lot more in play here: yes, it is quite normal that pixel-art based assets are defined multiple times, for varyng  screen-sizes in high-end games. Second: for non pixel-art dependant assets, still, if the assets are pixel based they will be faulty when scaled (jaggy or blurred) - the correct thing would be to draw the original assets in a pixel-independent way, and have a script to resize them to all needed sizes (that takes place eiter at "build" time, or at game-load time)

Comment: Not only does pixel art need rescaling, but the speed that everything in the game moves and accellerates needs tweaking as well. This is a very non-trivial change.

Comment: One "right" way to do this is, if using OpenGL or DirectX, one can set a resizing transformation that is applied to everything that is drawn to the screen (both position co-ords and things like sprite-size. This rescale is done by the graphics hardware and is effectively free, and one doesn't have to modify the game logic for positions or speeds - they can all be done to a standard scale, regardless of output resolution. I don't know Pygame enough to know whether it exposes such a thing, or if meddling with it breaks Pygame. It's relatively easy to do in Pyglet, for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could make a dummy surface at the design resolution and scale it to the resolution the game is running at:

```
window = pygame.set_mode([user_x, user_y])
w = pygame.Surface([design_x, design_y])

def draw():
    frame = pygame.transform.scale(w, (user_x, user_y))
    window.blit(frame, frame.get_rect())
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Draw everything on the dummy surface and it will be scaled to the screen. This requires a fixed screen height to screen width ratio.

Answer (score 4):

The best way to go about this is by downscaling images, in order to preserve image quality. Here are two options:

### Option 1

This method is probably the fastest.

1. Create images to be compatible with the largest resolution you are intending to support.
2. Create a screen with the user's desired size.

   ```
   screen = pygame.display.set_mode((user_x, user_y))
   ```
3. Downscale images at load time

   ```
   image = pygame.image.load("a.png").convert_alpha()
   pygame.transform.scale(image, (screen.width() / your_max_width, screen.height() / your_max_height), DestSurface=image)
   ```
4. Now, just blit them normally. It should run at normal speeds.

### Option 2

1. Create a screen with the user's desired size.

   ```
   screen = pygame.display.set_mode((user_x, user_y))
   ```
2. Next, create a **pygame.Surface** with the highest resolution *you* are intending to support.

   ```
   surface = pygame.Surface((1920, 1080))
   ```
3. Then, blit everything to that surface.

   ```
   surface.blit(image, rect)
   # Etc...
   ```
4. After all blits are completed, downscale the surface (as necessary) to whatever resolution the user desires. Preferably, you would only allow resolutions with the same aspect ratio.

   ```
   pygame.transform.scale(surface, ((screen.width() / your_max_width, screen.height() / your_max_height), DestSurface=surface)
   ```
5. Finally, blit the surface to the screen, and display it.

   ```
   screen.blit(surface, (0, 0))
   pygame.display.update()
   ```

This process (downscaling) allows you to preserve image quality while still allowing the user to choose their screen resolution. It will be slower because you are constantly manipulating images.

Comment: This technique does indeed work for me, I tested it both on static pictures and then in a game loop. However, in line 4 I have to copy from surface1 to surface2, then use surface2 in line5. That was the only way I could make it work. And it introduces noticeable choppiness / lag to the animation and scrolling. :( Looks pretty when scaling down tho.

Comment: Check out the edit I made. The first option listed should be sufficient for your needs. You are correct that the second option in my post will be slower.

Comment: I'm really liking how option 1 looks, that's almost certainly the method I will end up going with... I'm just not liking that I have to rethink how images get loaded and placed on the screen. Now I have to think of a new way to automatically calculate the correct position for images when you downscale to the desired resolution (either with image lists for each selectable resolution, or with some dynamic process). Either way, it's better than what I've found elsewhere on the web, thanks for the information. I'm marking this as the correct answer.

Comment: Option 1 is perfect for what I need. My sprites are designed in 1080p but I'm wondering if I should redo them at 4k and scale down as 1440p and 4k are on the up. Or I could just set the max resolution in the game to 1080p and scale up to screen size if higher? I suppose the question here is, do I expect 4k gamers to play my game (2D indie in Pygame? no!) in which case, I should probably leave it as 1080 and scale down using option 1?

Comment: @Jayce Yes, I would recommend option 1. As for which resolutions to support, I would recommend tackling any changes to sprite resolutions later. It's better to complete your game first, then worry about that. In the meantime, if you need to support something larger than 1080p, try upscaling and see if that looks reasonable for your game.

Comment: how would you upscale images?

Answer (score 3):

Spent some time tinkering and put together a demo showcasing how you could go about tackling this problem. Find yourself an image for testing and put the string path to that image in the script for the value of imagePath.

The functionality of this script is simple. As you hit either left or right on the arrow keys, the screen resolution cycles through a tuple of acceptable resolutions and the screen resizes accordingly while scaling your test image to the new resolution.

```
import pygame,sys
from pygame import *
from pygame.locals import *


displayIndex = 0
pygame.init()

##standard 16:9 display ratios
DISPLAYS = [(1024,576),(1152,648),(1280,720),(1600,900),(1920,1080),(2560,1440)] 
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(DISPLAYS[displayIndex])
screen.fill((0,0,0))
### change image path to a string that names an image you'd like to load for testing. I just used a smiley face from google image search.
### Put it in the same place as this file or set up your paths appropriately
imagePath = "Smiley-icon.png"


class Icon(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.smileyImage = pygame.image.load(imagePath)
        self.image = self.smileyImage.convert_alpha()
        ### need to assume a default scale, DISPLAYS[0] will be default for us
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.posX = x
        self.posY = y
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
        self.defaultx = (float(self.rect[2])/DISPLAYS[0][0])*100
        self.defaulty = (float(self.rect[3])/DISPLAYS[0][1])*100
        ## this is the percent of the screen that the image should take up in the x and y planes



    def updateSize(self,):
        self.image = ImageRescaler(self.smileyImage,(self.defaultx,self.defaulty))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = self.posX
        self.rect.y = self.posY


def ImageRescaler(image,originalScaleTuple): #be sure to restrict to only proper ratios
    newImage = pygame.transform.scale(image,(int(DISPLAYS[displayIndex][0]*(originalScaleTuple[0]/100)),
                                         int(DISPLAYS[displayIndex][1]*(originalScaleTuple[1]/100))))
    return newImage


def resizeDisplay():
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(DISPLAYS[displayIndex])
    ## this is where you'd have'd probably want your sprite groups set to resize themselves
    ## Just gonna call it on icon here
    icon.updateSize()


icon = Icon(100,100)
while True:
    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_LEFT:
                displayIndex -=1
                if displayIndex < 0:
                    displayIndex = 5
                resizeDisplay()
            elif event.key == K_RIGHT:
                displayIndex+=1
                if displayIndex > 5:
                    displayIndex = 0
                resizeDisplay()




    screen.blit(icon.image,(icon.rect.x,icon.rect.y))  
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: I extract textures from sprite sheets to build platforms, I use overlapping backgrounds, character graphics, mob graphics, projectiles etc. It really seems like this would be overly laborious in a game with lots of graphics loaded by more than one class. There has GOT to be a simpler way of doing this... I can see how something like this could work, I might try rewriting my code to use something like this if all else fails. I was really hoping for something easy like a second line of code that just resizes the image based on passed variables from a global constant (current screen resolution).

Comment: A simple way to go about it (but probably not ideal or great for performance) is to draw everything to a temporary surface and scale that entire surface instead of everything individually, then simply blit that to screen.

Comment: You have to have a mechanism to the scaiing at image loading time, and instead of using pygame.image.load, use your function that does teh scaling already.  @oxrock - the idea of upscaling the gamescreen is hideous - you have to render for the final size.

Comment: @jsbueno, I'm starting to think that something like this is the only way to maintain a decent frame rate. Blitting to various surfaces in an attempt to re-scale on the fly consumes too much time. There has to be a way to either A. simply load images with the correct size and scaling, or B. have a mechanism that scales right as the image is loaded. Argh, this is going to get messy.

Comment: If you are handlign your project in a pubic place, I won't mind helping you in a deeper way with that - jsut call me in private. my e-mail is on my profile page.